# How to quickly detect and switch off a shorted circuit (e.g. 30 VDC, 20 A intended, <5 ms response)

Tags: power-electronics, current-measurement, short-circuit, circuit-protection

## Summary

I'm designing a circuit that's meant to provide a short pulse of medium-low voltage, high-current, power from a capacitor bank to a low-resistance load, and I want to interrupt it if the resistance goes *too* low / the current goes *too* high. This seems like a sufficiently-common need that there have to be accepted standard ways to do that, but I'm not sure what they are.

I'm picturing a Hall effect sensor, a voltage comparator, and some kind of hysteresis loop and/or manual reset, with the output going into the enable logic for the MOSFET switches, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel badly.

## Application

Here's more context and detail, if it helps.  I'm making a "launcher" for model rockets, which is to say, a power supply for igniters that start the rocket motors burning. In my case, I want to fire multiple igniters (for multiple engines) simultaneously, so this is a multi-output power supply. The goal is to provide as much current as practical to all of the outputs for <= 300 ms. The ignitor is essentially a filament of 30-40 AWG nichrome wire, with a cold resistance of roughly 0.5 - 2 Ω. When things work as intended, "firing" an ignitor goes like this:

| time range | events |
| --- | --- |
| <0 | battery (low-current power supply) charges the capacitor(s) to >30 V |
| 0 | the enable signal goes high (or low, depending on the switch circuit design) |
| a few us | the power MOSFET is fully low-impedance. |
| 1-10 ms | the igniter filament gets hotter and resistance goes up (exact value not clear) |
| 20-100 ms | the igniter filament vaporizes and almost immediately ionizes. The plasma / ionized vapor is very low resistance (exact value not clear) |
| 30-110 ms | the expanding plasma no longer makes an electrical connection, and the circuit becomes open. |
|  | Ideally, this hot gas ignites the rocket motor. |

So, when everything works, the pulse is self-limited, starts when intentionally activated, and ends when the load has been vaporized. As currently designed, a single large EDLC capacitor bank feeds 4 separately-switched outputs/loads, and the energy sharing between them is implicit.  If one ignitor vaporizes before the others, it stops drawing current, and the remaining ones get more. The problem is that there are a lot of ways for an igniter wire to short out. It's not a rare failure mode so much as a common annoyance. And, in my current design, if one output gets shorted, it "steals" all the current from the other outputs, *and* discharges the capacitor(s).

The schematic below shows a simplified version of the circuit, without short circuit protection yet. The blue circles and lines indicate (notional) sensing and interrupt logic.

[image: Example application circuit]

## Objective

The figure below shows a (KiCad ngspice) simulation of a simplified "normal" pulse current profile for a single load, where all 4 output circuits are switched on at the same time, have the same (exactly 0.5 Ω) load, and are switched off after 300 ms. The design goal is to deliver at least 20 A *each* for well beyond the expected lifetime of the ignitor.

[image: Firing pulse current profile]

I want to allow a profile like this, while detecting and disconnecting a short circuit (which could be several hundred A) in a few ms. And I would like it to stay disconnected until explicitly reset by a control signal, and/or the whole system is de-energized.

Is there an off-the-shelf module solution for this, and/or a generally-accepted best practice?

Thanks!

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148044/discussion-on-question-by-eric-anderson-how-to-quickly-detect-and-switch-off-a-s); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put a light bulb in series with each igniter.

For your application, a [36V 400W GX6,35mm](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=36V+400W+GX6%2C35mm&iax=images&ia=images) will probably work well. It limits the current to 11A after about 100ms if the load is shorted. For a typical light bulb, the initial current is ten times the rated current, which should be enough to blow the igniter. In this case, the light bulb will not turn on at all and maintain low resistance.

A light bulb has very much the same characteristics as an igniter: low initial resistance, which rises tenfold in the first 100ms or so. The trick is to use a light bulb that is somewhat slower to blow than the igniter. The igniter gets hot first and limits the current through the light bulb, which stays cold and low resistance. If there is a short circuit, the light bulb ignites and does what the igniter failed to do.

Abusing light bulbs as slow blowing and self resetting fuses is common practice, most notably to protect the tweeter in loudspeakers. Back in the day, light bulbs were also used for automatic gain control in vacuum tube circuits. Here is an [EE Times article](https://www.eetimes.com/use-light-bulbs-as-current-limiters/) with some background information.

Comment: I'm accepting this as an answer.  It isn't really an _answer_ to the question as I asked it, but it's a good _solution_ to the underlying problem.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9PAOr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Split the capacitor into N pieces one for each e-match.  that way if one of them goes open or shorts it will not do anything to the others.

you probably want to charge the capacitors through diodes so as not to provide a path for equalising currents during discharge.

Comment: Assuming R1-R3 are the loads (e-matches) here, wouldn't I need some significant resistors and/or diodes between the capacitors to prevent them from just acting like a single larger capacitor and (all)  discharging through the shorted resistor?

Comment: @EricAnderson How would they do that? If R2 shorts, then C2 pushes equally back on C1 and C3 from a voltage perspective. The key here is that in order to empty any capacitor, you HAVE to go through the loads that you want them to.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm designing a circuit that's to provide a short pulse of medium-low voltage, high-current, power from a capacitor bank to a low-resistance load, and I want to interrupt it if the resistance goes too low / the current goes too high.

The simplest solution would be to avoid the problem, and have series-connected igniters with an active zener across them, so that a high impedance load would be bypassed. But that requires way more expensive capacitors and so on.

I'd use the channel resistance of a mosfet as a shunt, and then the mosfet can do the switching. The switching can be low-side for simplicity.

Let's refine the requirement: anytime the load current goes above the reference current, the load is turned off. The reference current is not static, but dynamic and triggered at the same time as the igniters are fired. It is "very high" initially and subsequently decays.

So, now we have three circuit blocks:

1. Dynamic reference threshold generator (say a reference voltage proportional to current)
2. Initial blanking delay - for the first couple of μs, the threshold comparator is inhibited and can't turn the load off
3. Current comparator between the load current and reference current

The reference current generator can be analog or digital, say an Arudino Uno driving an 8-bit parallel DAC. It'd be plenty fast for this application, and the DAC output update rate would decay as time progresses.

As for the circuit - there are many ways to do it of course. If I was asked to put it together from parts I have on hand, it'd look something like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f25DVw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

CD4000 logic family works great from 12V or even 15V, and that should be plenty to drive M1 into full conduction.

- CD4504 is a TTL-to-CMOS level converter. With inputs configured for TTL (pin 13 to VCC), it works well with 3.3V through 5V logic inputs,
- CD4041 is a good symmetric ±10mA driver that works fine for gate driving. They can be paralleled too if you want,
- CD4044 is an #S/#R latch,
- CD40106 is a Schmitt input inverter,
- CD40107 is an open-drain NAND gate,
- OA1: TL084 has a slew rate good enough for this application at gain 10. The slower TLC274 would also be "fast enough" for this relatively relaxed application, and would run with a single +12V supply.
- LM2901 is also a "good enough" comparator with open-collector output, thus needs the pull-up resistor R5,

D1 limits the input voltage to OA1 to keep it from saturating the output.

The current is sensed using the M1 channel resistance as a current shunt. The gain of OA1 can be adjusted to compensate for channel resistance differences between channels if so desired.

Of course different parts could be used - the above is a retro-design with all parts manufactured still in DIP packages by TI.

The reference voltage generator is another matter. An RC discharge could be a good starting point. But not RC discharge down to ground, but to some base current level that's acceptable.